# Better-SQLite3 Database resetting after restart on Heroku

Tags: javascript, sqlite, heroku, discord.js

I have a Discord bot with a [`better-sqlite3`](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3) database for coins and XP. It always worked fine until 2 weeks ago. Now, after every restart it just sets the XP and coins back. It's really annoying because people are leveling up to the same level every day.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be *very* surprised if this ever worked properly.

Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) loses all changes made to it whenever your dynos restart. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day). As a result, file-based databases like SQLite [aren't supported on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3).

You'll have to switch to a client-server database if you want to run your code on Heroku. PostgreSQL is a common choice, and Heroku provides its own [hosted PostgreSQL service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) that you can start using for free.

Comment: You can't use any file-based data store on Heroku except for temporary storage.

Comment: I don't think it's harder, and there are _plenty_ of tutorials out there. Hundreds. But that's irrelevant. Heroku doesn't provide a persistent filesystem. You _can't_ use SQLite on it, period, no matter how much you might want to (unless you're using it in a read-only context).

Comment: If you want some easy DB with Postgres use [`enmap@3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enmap/v/3.1.4) ( Version 4 doesnt support postgress anymore ) and use the [`enmap-postgress provoider`](https://github.com/eslachance/enmap-pgsql). This will allow you to use a structure like Discord.js Collections to store data presistant. ( enmap.set() / enmap.get() )